# I give...where is the "activitycreator.bat" file?

Tags: android

I'm very new to Android programming...well, programming in general!

Almost every tutorial out there for Android programming says to run "activitycreator.bat".  But where the heck is it?  It's not in the tools directory on my machine.  I've searched the whole drive and I don't have it.  Help!

Answer (score 1):

> Almost every tutorial out there for Android programming says to run "activitycreator.bat".

Only the old ones.

> But where the heck is it?

In Android 1.1. It was replaced in Android 1.5 with the `android create project` command.